# Can't access docker container exposed port

Tags: 14.04, docker, ruby-on-rails

I am running a rails app inside of a docker container but trying to reach it from a browser the browser shows `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` . when running `docker ps` I get

```
a086ed5a6c4a        rails                       "bash"                   3 days ago          Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                                                            rails
```

then when running `docker inspect rails` I see the gateway is `"Gateway": "172.17.0.1"`

when I try and `ping 172.17.0.1` it works but if I `ping 172.17.0.1:3000` it doesn't work.

when I try `nmap -p 3000 172.17.0.1` I get

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-12 15:27 PST
Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.1
Host is up (0.000047s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3000/tcp closed ppp
```

running `sudo netstat -tulpn` I get the following.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5940          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1900/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5965/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1195/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2910/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::5858                 :::*                    LISTEN      4693/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::4200                 :::*                    LISTEN      4629/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      4423/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      4665/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      1195/dnsmasq    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2910/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      4540/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      3099/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      4700/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::3002                 :::*                    LISTEN      6521/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::7357                 :::*                    LISTEN      4610/docker-proxy
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27824           0.0.0.0:*                           6091/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53717           0.0.0.0:*                           569/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           3206/chrome     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           569/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5699            0.0.0.0:*                           5961/dhclient   
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           5965/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1195/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           6091/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           5961/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           1336/cups-browsed
udp6       0      0 :::53862                :::*                                5961/dhclient   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                569/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                1195/dnsmasq    
udp6       0      0 :::59093                :::*                                569/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::26992                :::*                                6091/dhclient
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What happens if you simply type http://localhost:3000/ in your browser?  If nothing, are you running a firewall???

Answer (score 4):

I had to bind to 0.0.0.0 when running `rails server`. So I used `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` as explained in the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246254/cant-access-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that Rails isn't actually running in the container. In particular, the output of `docker ps` shows that the command running in the container is `bash`. That would mean that unless you have started it manually inside the container, Rails isn't running.